# Ajustar texto debajo de una imagen

Tags: html, css

**Esta es la imagen del resultado que quiero obtener:**
[image: Esto es lo que quiero obtener]

Como puedo hacer que un texto continué debajo de una imagen es decir que no deje un espacio en blanco abajo de la imagen, si no que continué...
**PD: Deben ejecutar el siguiente codigo en pantalla completa osea desktop.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
   .content_image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ececec;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="content_image">
     <h1>Imagen</h1>
    </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No termino de entender tu duda, pudieras agregar una muestra de lo que esperas obtener

Comment: Para eso podrias utilizar los Cards de bootstrap [Documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/)

Comment: Ya la he editado

Comment: Hola @zerokira, hace un tiempo respondí una duda similar a la tuya. Échale un vistazo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/215814/83304

Comment: @RuslanLópez Gacias